# Dropdown Component Unit Test Case using in sinon+chai : ng-forward

Tags: unit-testing, angular, sinon-chai

I want to write the unit test case for this component [Dropdown Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393431/how-to-pass-function-callback-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-ng-forw)

But I am unable to write the test case in sinon+chai using ng-forward.

Can somebody guide me in this.

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows what you have tried? Any error message? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, I am not getting where to start this ng-forward testing.